# need design suggestions for an efficient webcrawler that is going to parse 8M pages - Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-crawler

I'm going to develop a little crawler that's going to fetch a lot of pages from the same website, all of the requests are a change in the ID number of the url.

I need to save all of data I'll parse into a csv (nothing fancy), at most, I will crawl about 6M-8M pages, most of them doesn't contain the data I want, I know that there are about 400K pages which I need to parse, they are all similar in structure, I can't avoid crawl all the urls.

that's how the page looks when I get the data - http://pastebin.com/3DYPhPRg

that's when I don't get the data - http://pastebin.com/YwxXAmih

the data is saved in the spans inside the td's -

```
I need the data between ">" and "</span>".

<span id="lblCompanyNumber">520000472</span></td>
<span id="lblCompanyNameHeb">חברת החשמל לישראל בעמ</span></td>
<span id="lblStatus">פעילה</span></td>
<span id="lblCorporationType">חברה ציבורית</span></td>
<span id="lblGovCompanyType">חברה  ממשלתית</span></td>
<span id="lblLimitType">מוגבלת</span></td>
etc'
```

that's nothing too hard to parse from the document.

the problem is that it will take a few days to fetch the urls and parse them, it will consume a lot of memory and I think that it's going to crash here and then, which is very dangerous for me, it can't crash unless it can't run anymore.

I thought about -

```
 - fetching a url (urllib2)
      - if there's an error - move next (if it'll happen 5 times - I stop and save errors to log)
 - parse the html (still don't know whats best - BeautifulSoup \ lxml \
    scrapy \ HTMLParser etc')
      - if it's empty (lblCompanyNumber will be empty) save the ID in the emptyCsvFile.csv
 - else: save the data to goodResults.csv
```

the questions are -

1. which data types should I use in order to be more efficient and quick (for the data I parse and for the fetched content)?
2. which HTML parsing library should I use? maybe regex? the span id is fixed and doesn't change when there's data (again, efficient, speed, simplicity)
3. saving to file, keeping an handle to the file for so long etc' - is there a way that will take less resources and will be more efficient to save save the data? (400K lines at least)
4. any other thing I haven't thought about and I need to deal with, and maybe some optimization tips :)

another solution I thought of is using wget, save all pages to disk and then delete all the files who has the same md5sum of an empty document, the only problem is that I'm not saving the empty IDs.

by the way, I need to use py2exe and make an exe out of it, so things like scrapy can be hard to use here (it's known to cause issues with py2exe).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used httplib2 for this kind of thing because there are supposed to be memory leaks in the Python standard library routines. Also, httplib2 can be configured to keep a cache which might be useful if you have to restart and redo some pages.

I only ran through 1.7 million pages plus about 200000 from another server, so I can't comment on the volume you expect.

But I drove it all using AMQP with a topic exchange and persistent message queues (delivery_mode=2). This fed ny ids into the worker that used httplib2 and made sure that every id was retrieved. I tracked them using a memcache that was persisted using Tokyo Tyrant hash table on disk. I was able to shut down and restart the workers and move them between machines without missing any ids. I've had the worker running for up two three weeks at a time before I killed it to tinker with it.

Also, I used lxml for parsing responses because it is fast.

Oh, and after a page was retrieved and processed successfully, I posted the id as a message to a completed queue. Then later I manual copied the messages off of that queue and compared it to the input list to make sure that the whole process was reliable.

For AMQP I used amqplib with RabbitMQ as the broker. Nowadays I would recommend taking a look at haigha for AMQP. Although its documentation is sparse its model closely follows the AMQP 0.9.1 spec documents so you can use those to figure out options etc.

@YSY: I can't cut and paste the code because I did it at work, however it was nothing special. Just a loop with try: except: wrapped around the http request. Something like this:

```
retries = 5
while retries > 0:
    requestSucceeded = True # assume the best
    try:
        resp, content = h.request("http://www.example.com/db/1234567")
        if resp is None:
            requestSucceeded = False
            log.warn ("1234567: no http response")
        elif resp.status != 200:
            requestSucceeded = False
            log.warn ("1234567: replied with {0:d}".format(resp.status))
    except Exception as e:
        requestSuceeded = False
        log.warn("1234567: exception - " + str(e)) 
    if not requestSucceeded:
        time.sleep(30)
        retries -= 1
    else:
        retries = 0
if requestSucceded:
    process_request()
    ack_message()
```

The llop deals with two types of failures, one where the HTTP server talks to us but does not return a reply, and one where there is an exception, maybe a network error or anything else. You could be more sophisticated and handle different failure conditions in different ways. But this generally works. Tweak the sleep time and retries until you get over 90% success rate, then handle the rest later. I believe I'm using half hour sleeps and 3 retries right now, or maybe it is 15 minute sleeps. Not important really.

After a full run through, I process the results (log, and the list of completed messages) to make sure that they agree, and any documents that failed to retrieve, I try again another day before giving up. Of course, I would scan through the logs looking for similar problems and tweaking my code to deal with them if I could think of a way.

Or you could google "scrapy". That might work for you. Personally, I like using AMQP to control the whole process.

Comment: it sounds like you've written a very impressive and strong crawler, as a matter of fact I had some weird issues with urllib2 (it sent GET, didn't wait for response and skipped to the next request (seen several times with wireshark). I'll try using httplib2 too.
btw - it would be great to see snipets of your code (I'm sure many of us will learn a lot of seeing and testing it).

Comment: can you please explain - "I was able to shut down and restart the workers and move them between machines without missing any ids" how did you do that? can you show a sample "worker"? how did you verify you got a response for every request? there are things that can't be monitored cause of server errors.

Comment: If you use delivery-mode=2 when sending a message, then it stays in the queue until a worker receives it and acks it. My code just did not ack a message until I had successfully downloaded and processed the page whose id was in the message. After acking the message I recorded the id in a list of completed tasks to compare with the original list of tasks. Of course, if a web server just never responds (I retried 5 times at 30 minute intervals) there is not much you can do.

Comment: I would really like to see how you implemented the code that fetches the url and retries if fails, did you save the ids that gave you errors and kept on or have you stopped the crawling and waited?